# Significance of %x and ~

Tags: c, printf

```
int m=32
printf("%x" , ~m);
```

Output of this statement is `ffdf` and without `~` output is `20`.
What is the significance of `%x` and `~`?

Comment: You might want to go through some of your old questions and accept the best answers, otherwise people may not want to provide as helpful answers.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `~` operator is bitwise negation. It will print bitwise negation of `m`'s value. `%x` means that `printf` will output its value in hexadecimal format.

So, value `0xffdf` is the negation of value `0x20` (32).

Value 32 (int bits would be):

```
0000 0000 0010 0000
```

Its bitwise negation will be:

```
1111 1111 1101 1111
```

Which makes sense since:

```
1111 1111 = 0xff
```

And:

```
1101 1111 = 0xdf
```

Answer (score 7):

The `%x` is the [`printf` format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholders) that indicates that the `int` value should be displayed in hexadecimal.

The `~` is [bitwise NOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT), which flips all the bits in the integer.

The statement:

```
printf("%x", m);
```

will display the output `20` as `0x20` = decimal `32`.

The statement:

```
printf("%x", ~m);
```

will display the output `ffdf` as `0xffdf` is the bitwise inverse of `0x20`.

It may make more sense to visualize the bitwise negation in binary:

```
Base 10:         32                  65503
Base 16:        0x20                0xFFDF
Base 2:    0000000000100000    1111111111011111
```

Answer (score 2):

It means that `x` should have probably have been declared `unsigned` rather than `int`.

The `"%x"` printf format requires an `unsigned int` argument, and prints its value in hexadecimal (base 16).  You can safely use it with an `int` argument *if* the value is within the range representable either as an `int` or as an `unsigned int` (i.e., 0 .. `INT_MAX`).  Using `"%x"` with a negative `int` value, as this code fragment does, strictly speaking has undefined behavior, though the actual behavior is likely to be reasonably consistent.

The C standard says:

> The result of the **~** operator is the bitwise complement of its
>   (promoted) operand (that is, each bit in the result is set if and only
>   if the corresponding bit in the converted operand is not set).

Note that it's defined in terms of the *representation* of the operand, not its value.

The output you describe indicates that you're using a system with two's-complement signed integers where `int` is only 16 bits, which is unusual these days.  (Are you using an ancient Turbo C compiler or something similar?)  On my system, this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int m = 32;
    printf("%x\n" , ~m);
    return 0;
}
```

produces this output:

```
ffffffdf
```

(Note that I've added the required `#include <stdio.h>` and a semicolon on the declaration of `m`.)

Answer (score 2):

The `~` symbol represents the **bitwise NOT**, or **complement operator**; *a unary operation that performs logical negation on each bit*, forming the ones' complement of the given binary value. Binary digits that are 0 become 1, and those that are 1 become 0.

32 is 00100000 in binary, and ~32 is 11011111 in binary (or 223 in decimal).

The `%x` option in the `printf` function will display a unsigned hexadecimal format (using lowercase letters).

So,

```
printf("%x", m); // displays the hexadecimal value of 32 (00100000), "20"

printf("%x", ~m); // displays the hexadecimal value of ~32 (11101111), "ffdf"
```

[Sources]
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string

Answer (score 1):

And %x means you print the value of x in hexadecimale.

Answer (score 1):

~32 = -33 use unsigned int to get results